# facebook LIKE button for each image on the page

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am building a contest on my website, through which users can upload image on my website and finally one page will show all the images from all users (using infinite scrolling). Now i will have to decide the winner after the contest ends.

when users will visit the page, they will see all the photos on one page. when they hover over it, they get a LIKE button for that photo. once they LIKE it, i need to get the LIKE count for that photo from facebook and store it in my DB against that photo record.

I have included FB LIKE on my webpages before, BUT that was using Unique URL of the webpage and then i used to get the LIKE count by sending that URL. BUT in this case i am not aware how can i implement FB Like button for each photo and get the count as the URL of the page will be the same for all of the photos.

need to implement this ASP.NET 3.0

I have searched online with no luck. I am not including any code as i am not even sure where to begin.

Please help.

Comment: Using the Like button for some kind of “vote” is against Facebook’s terms I think.

Comment: dont know about this BUT we are just collecting counts and thats it...